# How can I customize certain items inside of a navigation bar in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation bar but I'm having a lot of trouble making changes to separate elements without changing every single item in the nav bar.

For example, if I wanted more padding/space between for only one element in the nav bar (in between the name and other elements such as projects, resume, etc), how would I achieve that? Or even if I wanted to change the text size for a single item in the nav bar (Make first name bigger than the rest).

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#First Name">First Name</a>
    <a href="#Projects">Projects</a>
    <a href="#Resume">Resume</a>
    <a href="#About">About</a>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    .navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: white;
        position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
        top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;

    }

    .navbar a {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 30px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 200%;
    }
```

Comment: You may use `:nth-child` or `:nth-of-type` selector but maybe it would be better to assign additional class to elements that need to have special styles. So in case when you modify navbar styles would not mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is with `:first-of-type` or `nth-of-type(1)`. This selects, in this case, the first anchor element inside of `navbar`. You can change the argument in `nth-of-type` to select any element in the menu.

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0;
  /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.navbar a:nth-of-type(1) {
  padding-right: 20px;
  background: #777;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#First Name">First Name</a>
  <a href="#Projects">Projects</a>
  <a href="#Resume">Resume</a>
  <a href="#About">About</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `:nth-child` selector. Please take a look to this page: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/